# CefSharp ChromiumWebBrowser Navigating event

Tags: wpf, chromium, cefsharp

What event needs to be intercepted in ChromiumWebBrowser, so that you can cancel the page load?

In the standard WebBrowser, this was done by intercepting the Navigation events and setting the NavigationCancelEventArgs.Cancel values to true.

Comment: I do think, that you can use `IRequestHandler.OnBeforeBrowse` for this. See [`DefaultRequestHandler`](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/master/CefSharp/Handler/DefaultRequestHandler.cs) for a base class to derive from.

Comment: This class has since been renamed. Link; https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/master/CefSharp/Handler/RequestHandler.cs